# Is there any limit to store the files inside the app-specific storage[data/data/{packagename}] in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, memory-management, local-storage, android-storage

Usecase: I would like to store the files into the app-specific storage completely so that no one can access the files directly.

I have stored files into the internal storage[storage/emulated/xxx/xxx] and app-specific storage[data/data/com.x.x]but I didn't get any exceptions from the device until storage is full. I couldn't find anything about the restriction of app-specific storage in Android Docs, is there any limit really? Please find the devices which I have tested below.

1. Samsung Tab 32GB    [Stored up to 20GB in app-specific storage]
2. Samsung S10 128GB   [Stored up to 100GB in app-specific storage]
3. OnePlus7 128GB      [Stored up to 100GB in app-specific storage]

As per my R&D on app-specific storage, there are no limitations. But I can't find this in the Android documentation. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: The app specific storages are two. /data/data/<appname> and /storage/emulated/0/Android/data<appname>. You should consider both as they are on different 'partitions' and can have a different file system. The first one is mostly pretty small.

Comment: Yes, there may be two partitions. If the first one(data/data/<appname>) is small, I should get exception somewhere right? but I didn't get any. How can we make sure that the first one is small?

Tested devices:
1.Samsung Tab 32GB [Stored up to 20GB in app-specific storage]
2.Samsung S10 128GB [Stored up to 100GB in app-specific storage]
3.OnePlus7 128GB [Stored up to 100GB in app-specific storage]

Comment: `[Stored up to 100GB in app-specific storage]` In which one? There are two we know.

Comment: If the first one(data/data/<appname>) ` It is /data/data/<appname>.

Comment: Yes. In app-specific storage [ /data/data/<appname>]. If that is limited, how is it possible?

Comment: I expect you to post too values for every device. One for each app specific storage.

Comment: Ok. Let me explain what I have tested on Samsung Tab which is running on 7.0 and having the 32GB. In that system occupies around 8GB and some other media files occupy 2GB, now the total occupied storage on device 10 GB and free space is 20GB.  I can use a total of 20GB for app-specific storage for only my application.

Device Storage Summary 
System storage: 8GB
Media&others : 2GB
My app(only in app-specific storage) : 20GB
Total :32GB

I have also tested the same scenarios on other devices which I have mentioned

Comment: That is not the info i asked for . And I do not believe that you can write 20 GB to /data/data/<appname>.

Comment: Ok. but it is true, I have tested. Do you need any other info to answer this question?

Comment: Sorry... but what is your question now exactly? You now know all i would say.

Comment: How's it going @VenkateshPrasadShanigaram? Do you decide to use `/data/data/<appname>` to store your data? 

And does it limit max size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is no storage limit specified in the android document. But it mentioned that **"Internal storage has limited space for app-specific data. Use other types of storage if you need to save a substantial amount of data."**

You can write the multiple files unless storage is available otherwise it will throw the **IOException**.

It is also mentioned that **"if you read or write the same files for multiple times then it can impact the application performance"** if you are using app-specific storage.

It basically stores the files that are meant for your app's use only.

So choose storage wisely.

You can read more information [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage) or [Android Dev Summit '19](http://%20https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UnJ3amzJM94).

I hope it helps you!

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I still have questions. 
As per Android doc, "has limited space for app-specific data". Actually this sentence is confusing. What does it exactly mean? Does it mean app can store up to say 4GB or 5GB or XGB? If this sentence is true why I am not getting any memory exception when filled app storage entirely with files.

Comment: I don't know about the exact allocation size. I guess the system allocates the size to app-storage. But yeah one thing is mentioned that it is always a small amount of storage allocation. you can read it here. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific#internal